# Jquery random/shuffle content amongst multiple columns?

Tags: jquery, shuffle, multiple-columns

I have a three-column layout, and each column has multiple divs that hold blocks of similar content:

```
<section class="info-blocks-container clearfix">
<div id="col1">
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
</div>
<div id="col2">
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
</div>
<div id="col3">
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
    <div class="info-block">...</div>
</div>
</section>
```

I'd like to shuffle the children divs within `div#col1`, `div#col2`, and `div#col3` amongst the columns randomly, so some of `#col1`'s child divs end up in `#col2` and/or `#col3`, and vice-versa. I'm using thecodeparadox's `function reorder()` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296247/how-to-sort-a-random-div-order-in-jquery) (I removed the 'undo' function) and the shuffling is working, but 
1. the way I have 3 separate duplicate functions is very dirty, and 
2. it's only sorting the divs within each column (it's not sharing the children divs among the three columns):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    reorder();
    reorder2();
    reorder3();

    function reorder() {
        var grp = $(".info-blocks-container > div:nth-child(1)").children();
        var cnt = grp.length;

        var temp, x;
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            temp = grp[i];
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cnt);
            grp[i] = grp[x];
            grp[x] = temp;
        }
        $(grp).remove();
        $(".info-blocks-container > div:nth-child(1)").append($(grp));
    }
    function reorder2() {
        var grp = $(".info-blocks-container > div:nth-child(2)").children();
        var cnt = grp.length;

        var temp, x;
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            temp = grp[i];
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cnt);
            grp[i] = grp[x];
            grp[x] = temp;
        }
        $(grp).remove();
        $(".info-blocks-container > div:nth-child(2)").append($(grp));
    }
    function reorder3() {
        var grp = $(".info-blocks-container > div:nth-child(3)").children();
        var cnt = grp.length;

        var temp, x;
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            temp = grp[i];
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cnt);
            grp[i] = grp[x];
            grp[x] = temp;
        }
        $(grp).remove();
        $(".info-blocks-container > div:nth-child(3)").append($(grp));
    }
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At second, your problem was a really a challenge for me. But I think I found **a** solution:

```
var columnsCollection = new Array();
var columnsObjectsNumber = new Array();

reorder();
function reorder() {
    $(".info-blocks-container").find("DIV[id^='col']").each(function()
    {           
        var tmp = $(this).children();
        //Store the numbers of contained children
        columnsObjectsNumber.push($(tmp).size());
        $(tmp).each(function()
        {
            //transfers current child object to our global store place
            columnsCollection.push($(this));
            //and removed it
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    var restartIndex = 0;
    $(".info-blocks-container").find("DIV[id^='col']").each(function()
    {
        //Contains the random generated number
        var x;
        //Contains the current object with Id 'col..'
        var temp = $(this);
        for (var i = 0; i < columnsObjectsNumber[restartIndex]; i++)
        {
            /*
              Generates a random number.
             The maximum limit is the current length from our global store place
            */
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * columnsCollection.length);
            //Appends the object to the current object with Id 'col..'
            $(temp).append(columnsCollection[x]);
            //Removes the appended element from global store place
            columnsCollection.splice(x,1);
         }
        restartIndex++;
    });   
}
```

It doesn't looks professional, but it works. Hopefully it is what you requested for...

Answer (score 1):

At first, you don't need three functions there looks similar. You can cast it just in one method:

```
reorder();
function reorder(columnObject) {
    $(".info-blocks-container").find("DIV[id^='col']").each(function()
    {
        var grp = $(this).children();
        var cnt = grp.length;
        var temp, x;
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            temp = grp[i];
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cnt);
            grp[i] = grp[x];
            grp[x] = temp;
         }
         $(grp).remove();
         $(this).append($(grp));  
    });
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! As soon as I get a chance to test fully, I'll mark one of these as the answer