# how to swap ramdom the position of multiple divs when refresh website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to swap them that its position was arranged available?
How to use jquery to swap the position of multiple divs in refresh page?

Example:

> info1 Info2 info3 info4
>
> info5 info6 info7 info8

How swap random :

> info1 info3 info5 info6
>
> info4 info2 info7 ...v.v.

This CSS:

```
    .section_13{ width:280px; float:left; margin:0 0 40px 40px; }
    .section_13:hover{  margin: 0px auto;
        cursor:pointer;
        background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.1);
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
                    inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  img.feat_thumb{float:left;}

    .feat_details{width:180px;float:left;padding:0 0 0 10px;}
    .test_right{width:315px;float:left;padding:0 0 0 10px; }
    p.feat_text{font-style:italic; letter-spacing:5px;  position: relative; margin-top:100px; margin-left: 30px;}
    .testimonial{ border-bottom:1px dotted #ddd; padding:0 0 10px 0; margin:0px 0 0px 0; clear:both; float:left;}

    .section_13 ul{padding:15px 0 25px 0; margin:0px; list-style:none;}
    .section_13 ul li{padding:7px 0 7px 0; margin:0px;border-bottom:1px dotted #ddd; line-height:19px;}
    .section_13 ul li a{ padding:0 0 0 15px;}
    .section_13 ul li a:hover{color:#000000;}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info1</h4>
        <p>info1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info2</h4>
        <p>info2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info3</h4>
        <p>info3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info4</h4>
        <p>info4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info5</h4>
        <p>info5</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info6</h4>
        <p>info6</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info7</h4>
        <p>info7</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info8</h4>
        <p>info 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section_13">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" class="feat_thumb" />
    <div class="feat_details">
         <h4>info9</h4>
        <p>info9</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is htis what you are looking for http://isotope.metafizzy.co/?

Comment: wow.. How to work? and how auto ramdom it? thanks

Comment: Maybe [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296247/how-to-sort-a-random-div-order-in-jquery) has what you are looking for.